# many to many association mass assign checkboxes ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, many-to-many, has-many-through, join

what i want to accomplish it's almost exactly the same as [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised)!
railscast tutorial but can't get it to work.I have a courses table and a enrollments table they have a many to many relation so i have a join table called "courses_enrollments" i'd like to be able to add many courses to enrollments all at once from a form... i used a has_many_through relation and looped through all the courses in the form and for each of them i have a checkbox so i can add them to enrollments but when i save nothing happens my join table (courses_enrollments) never gets filled with the relations i want.... here are my models:

courses:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :courses_enrollments
    has_many :enrollments, :through => :courses_enrollments
```

enrollments:

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :courses_enrollments
    has_many :courses, :through => :courses_enrollments
```

and courses_enrollments:

```
class CoursesEnrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :courses
    belongs_to :enrollments
end
```

and finally my enrollments form view:

```
<%= form_for(@enrollment) do |f| %>
  <% if @enrollment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@enrollment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this enrollment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @enrollment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :state %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:state, Courses.all, :id, :name, {:include_blank => true}, {:multiple => false}) %>
  </div>
```

I also tried it like this in the form.... but nothing gets saved here either

```
 <% Courses.all.each do |course|%>
    <%= check_box_tag "enrollment[course_id][]", course.id %>
    <%= course.name %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

i want to be able to save many records to the join table that holds the relation between the enrollments i am creating or updating and the courses i selected with the has many through association.... appreciate the help

Comment: It would be a good idea to look at your development log and see what the database SQL is being produced and the status of each SQL statement executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :enrollments
```

---

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
```

with this type of association you end up with a join table which will have `course_id` and `enrollment_id` . Thus not needing to create a new model just to handle your association. Rails already does that for you.

After that, in your controllers, make sure the accepted_params have this:

Controllers:

```
def course_params
  params.require(:course).permit(
    ...
    enrollments_ids: []
```

---

```
def enrollment_params
  params.require(:enrollment).permit(
    ...
    courses_ids: []
```

Comment: i tried it it still isn't saving anything to the joing table... i've had issues with this associations since i started with rails (like 2 months ago) i tried it your way and tried with `has_many_through` and the same thing happens it doesn't throws any erros but it keeps not saving in the join table.... if u think of anything else let me know man thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/studio51/web-booqmark.it , have a look at my app. I'm doing a HABTM association between `collections` and `bookmarks` . And it works fine for me. Have a look in the `models` `controllers` `views` and `db/migrations` . Let me know if it helped you or not.

Comment: yes it did man thanx i was naming the join table wrong... thank you now i kind of have another issue.... i now need `has_many_through` relation cause i have some tables related that need that association like for example my `:courses` table has many `:topics` and topics can be in many courses as well through the table `:weeks` and in weeks i save the fk for `:courses` and `:topics` plus some additional attributes like display order and week number..... do you have any idea on haw to work with thad? if you do i'd appreciate the help .

Comment: That's a bit hard to tell from this post. Could you put your models in a gist please? https://gist.github.com/